# Leer JSON proveniente de PHP con Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, json

Tengo un problema para averiguar como meter un Json en un ciclo para leer todos los datos del arreglo y poder generar variables con JS.

De esta manera creo el arreglo Json

```
function info(){
    global $conn;

    //Query a seleccionar en la base de datos
    $query = "SELECT permisos.idTipoMeta, tiposmetas.nombreMeta, permisos.hab FROM `permisos` 
                INNER JOIN tiposmetas ON permisos.idTipoMeta = tiposmetas.idTipoMeta
                WHERE idUsuario = " . $_GET['idUsuario'];

    //Se ejecuta el query y si no se puede pasar a $result, hubo un problema con el query
    if(!$result = $conn->query($query)){
        die('Ha ocurrido un error ejecutando la solicitud. Error: [' . $conn->error . ']');
    }

    $output = array();

    while($tRow = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $row = array();
        $keys = array_keys($tRow);

        for ($i = 0; $i<count($tRow); $i++){
        // if($keys[$i] != "SuspendidoProv" ){   //agregar todas las columnas excepto "SuspendidoProv" que se agregará en un input
            $row[] = $tRow[$keys[$i]];
        // }
        }

        $output['aaData'][] = $row;

    }   

    //Imprime la salida como un arreglo codificado en JSON     
    echo json_encode($output);

    $conn->close();
}
```

He intentado llamarlo de la siguiente manera para meterlo dentro de un ciclo `for`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
                output[i]
            }
```

Pero me sale que no está definida la variable. Entonce revisé la consola de chrome para saber qué nombre está obteniendo y me aparece:

```
{aaData: [["1", "FACTURADO", "0"], ["2", "COBRANZA", "1"], ["3", "PROSPECTOS POTENCIALES", "1"],…]
```

Lo cual quiere decir que sí se están enviando los datos, pero con el nombre `aaData` pero aún cambiando por este nombre no logro averiguar cómo leer estos datos con Javascript.

Agrego el codigo con el cual enlazo el archivo php con js por medio de AJAX

```
$.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url : 'usuarios-get.php?act='+ act +'&idUsuario='+ idUsuario,
        success: function(response){
```

El archivo PHP es `usuarios-get.php`.

Comment: podrias agregar tu codigo de como intentas recibir diccho json en javascript y quien o como llamas a tu archivo php...que retorna dicho json

Comment: lo mando llamar por medio de ajax, agregue el código arriba

Comment: valida primero el json: https://jsonlint.com/   y si es válido lo recorres con $(response).each(function(key,value){console.log(key,value)})

Comment: en el evento success puedes obtener el response o data que retorna de tu php, algo asi....console.log(response);... con esto ves lo que retorna... ahora para acceder seria algo asi: var result = response.aaData;....luego mediante un ciclo for recorres uno a uno los registros de result

Comment: for(var i=0; result.legth<0; i++){...alert(result[i]);..}.. esa es la idea...

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque el autor decidió implementar todo de manera diferente y probablemente no pruebe ninguna respuesta propuesta (ni la marque como correcta).

Answer (score 1):

Si el console está devolviendo literalmente

```
{aaData: [["1", "FACTURADO", "0"], ["2", "COBRANZA", "1"], ["3", "PROSPECTOS POTENCIALES", "1"],…]
```

quiere decir que lo estas recibiendo como un `string`.

Deberías parsear el mismo en el objeto antes de recorrerlo.

```
var output = JSON.parse(output);
```

Para asegurarte que solo tenga array prueba  también sacando los datos que podrían estar mal en el string

```
var output = JSON.parse(output.replace("{aaData:","").repalce("}","") );
```

Espero te sea de utilidad.

Comment: Ya lo intente y no me funciono me aparece la siguiente leyenda "Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0"

Comment: Por que tienes   $output['aaData'][] = $row; en lugar de  $output[] = $row; ?? - Para que le agregas el aaData ?

Answer (score 1):

Mi estimado, hay dos circunstancias que tomar en cuenta:

#### 1. jQuery y el tipo de respuesta.

JQuery nos dice en la documentación:

> **dataType** (default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html))
>
> Type: String.
>
> The type of data that you're expecting back from the server. If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of the response (an XML MIME type will yield XML, in 1.4 JSON will yield a JavaScript object, in 1.4 script will execute the script, and anything else will be returned as a string). The available types (and the result passed as the first argument to your success callback) are:
>
> ...
>
> "json": Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript object... The JSON data is parsed in a strict manner; any malformed JSON is rejected and a parse error is thrown. As of jQuery 1.9, an empty response is also rejected; the server should return a response of null or {} instead. (See json.org for more information on proper JSON formatting.)

En resumen, sí especificas el tipo de dato esperado como **json**, jQuery devolverá la respuesta ya como objeto de Js dentro de la promesa resulta ([deferred.done](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/)), por lo que no hay necesidad de aplicar un *parse*.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://mi-dominio.mx/json',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (object) {
    object.aaData; // se puede trabajar como objeto.
  }
});
```

Cualquier otro resultado o problema con la sintaxis del JSON, causará un error, por lo que aunque se haya recibido respuesta del servidor, la función `success` no se ejecutará.

#### 2. Cabeceras de respuesta en PHP

Desde PHP debes indicar el encabezado de respuesta para el tipo de contenido que devuelves.

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($array);
```

#### Conclusión

En teoría deberías estar recibiendo un objeto en el parámetro de la función anónima en *success* sin hacer ninguna otra cosa.

Si quieres saber más información sobre como trabajar con objetos en Js, te recomiendo la siguiente lectura: [Objects: the basics](http://javascript.info/object-basics).